# Why data retrieved from database was added to php array two times?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a simple user table with columns: username, password, email, name, surname, birthdate, address and city. the first three are mandatory but the rest of them can be null.
I am connecting to the database and fetch rows in an array and print it.

```
$dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$sql = "select * from user"; 
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die("query exec error");
//$json = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($data)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        //$json['Kullanici'][]=$row;
        print_r($row);
        echo "<br /><br />";
    }
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
//echo json_encode($json);
```

But the output is like this:

```
Array ( [0] => ayse [username] => ayse [1] => b1b3773a05c0ed0176787a4f1574ff0075f7521e [password] => b1b3773a05c0ed0176787a4f1574ff0075f7521e [2] => ayse@hotmail.com [email] => ayse@hotmail.com [3] => [name] => [4] => [surname] => [5] => 0000-00-00 [birthdate] => 0000-00-00 [6] => [address] => [7] => istanbul [city] => istanbul )

Array ( [0] => baris [username] => baris [1] => 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b [password] => 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b [2] => bakkurt@hotmail.com [email] => bakkurt@hotmail.com [3] => BarÄ±ÅŸ [name] => BarÄ±ÅŸ [4] => [surname] => [5] => 0000-00-00 [birthdate] => 0000-00-00 [6] => [address] => [7] => [city] => )
```

The question is why there is  both [0]=>baris and [username] => baris. I was expecting only the username=>baris. Was I wrong? Where am i missing?
If i solve this problem, I will convert the array to json by removing comments.

Comment: try `print` or `echo` rather than `print_r`

Comment: it gives me an error.

Comment: It is expected behaviour meticulously explained in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem, if you look at the PHP documentation  for the `mysqli_fetch_array()` function, it accepts a parameter `resulttype`; it determines whether to return records as arrays with numeric indices alone, associative indices alone or both (which is what you have).
By default, the function uses `MYSQLI_BOTH`.
To get as numeric indices alone:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    //this will always return with numeric indices alone
}
```

For more information check here [PHP mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: thank you, I should look at the documentation first. my fault.

Answer (score 1):

if you need only `username => baris`

Try **[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**.

> **Courtesy** - **http://www.php.net**
>
> It returns an associative array of strings representing the fetched row
>   in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of
>   one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in
>   resultset.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the resulttype parameter. Have a look at this page: [mysqli_result::fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

You probably want to call the fetch_array function like this:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

`mysqli_fetch_array()` fetch data as both enumerated and associative, so if you only need associative array use `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

You can also [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) if you want to know something more about it.